# Laravel 8, response json return float value as string

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using query builder to get the data

```
DB::table('products')->get()
```

the results is

```
{"data" : [
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Product A",
     "price": "100000"
   },
   {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Product B",
     "price": "150000"
   }
  ]
}
```

how to cast the price back to float?
I have used `$casts = ["price" =>  "float"]` but it doesn't work since I'm not using eloquent

Comment: you can use Resource

Comment: So, have you tried to do like so, `$casts = ["data.price" => "float"]`

Comment: please share your database configuration setting from datbase.php file hidding ip and credentials

Comment: If you have a data model, try getting the result through that instead of the `DB::table` call. So, maybe `Product::all()` instead. I'm noticing `DB::` calls are also quoting my data which I'll likely post-process the result before it's converted to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
"price": "150000"
```

The "price" is set as string. You need to change to number.

```
"price": 150000
```

Comment: in my database the price is an integer data type

Comment: I think maybe in the DB query command, the "price" is converted to a string.

Comment: I think what you can do when you want to do something with the variable you can typecast it by using something like ```(float) $price```